# How to sum only the first row for each group in a result set

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Ok, I will try to explain myself the best I can, but I have the following:

I have a datasource that basically is a dynamic query. The query in itself shows 3 fields, Name, Amount1, Amount2.

Now, I could have rows with the same Name. The idea is to make a sum of Amount1+Amount2 WHEN Name is distinct from the previous one I saved. If I would do this on C# it could be something like this:

```
    foreach (DataRow dr in repDset.Dataset.Rows)
    {
        total = (long)dr["Amount1"] + (long)dr["Amount2"];
        if (thisconditiontrue)
        {
            if (PreviousName == "" || PreviousName != dr["Name"].ToString())
            {
                TotalName = TotalName + total;
            }
            PreviousName = dr["Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

The idea is to grab this and make a Reporting Services expression using the methods RS can give me, for example:

```
IIF(Fields!Name.Value<>Previous(Fields!Name.Value),Fields!Amount1.Value + Fields!Amount2.Value,False)
```

Something like that but that stores the amount of the previous one.

Maybe creating another field? a calculated one?

I can clarify further and edit if needed.

*EDIT for visual clarification:
As an example, it is something like this:
[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Your example C# code looks like it calculates a total in the foreach and then does an if statement and then exits. Are your brackets out of place? The numbers in your visual clarification don't add up either. Where does 26 come from? Where is your group total? I do not understand what you're trying to achieve... What is your data source? It sounds like something that can be done by partitioning the SUM() operator in SQL Server but that is only if you're using SQL server. Can you show us the query that you're using?

Comment: Hello Mike, I can't put the query here is it is huge, as I stated before it is kind of weird. The C# Code was just an example, but the idea is the following:

Take the visual example. for each different Name, grab the 1st one, sum Amount1+Amount2, that is why 26.

Stack: Amount1 (1) + Amount2 (0) = 1. 
Ignore the other "Stacks", when you encounter the 1st "Overflow" Sum: Amount1 (9) + Amount2 (16)
So: 1 + 25 = 26.

I will Edit the C# Code in my initial post so I can clarify it better.

Comment: I've given a solution that uses SQL to achieve the results you're after. If you really need an SSRS expression solution it is probably possible but it won't be as simple.

Answer (score -1):

This query is assuming you're working with SQL server. But you're going to need something to order the query results by otherwise how do you know which row is the first one?

```
SELECT SUM(NameTotal) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Amount1 + Amount2 AS NameTotal,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderField PARTITION BY Name) AS rowNum
    FROM srcTable
) AS a
WHERE rowNum=1;
```

This uses the analytical window function [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186734.aspx) to number each row and the PARTITION BY clause tells it to reset the numbering for every different value of Name in the result set. You do need a field that you can order the results by though or this won't work. If you really just want a random order you can do `ORDER BY NEWID()` but that will give you a non-deterministic result.

This syntax is particular to SQL server but it can usually be achieved in other databases.

If you're looking to display the output like you've shown in your example you could use two queries and reference the other one by passing it as the scope to an aggregate function in an SSRS expression like this:

```
=MAX(Fields!Total.Value, "TotalQueryDataset")
```

Where your dataset is called "TotalQueryDataset".

Otherwise you can achieve the output using pure SQL like this:

```
WITH nameTotals AS (
    SELECT Name, Amount1, Amount2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderField PARTITION BY Name) AS rowNum
    FROM srcTable
)
SELECT Name, Amount1, Amount2
FROM nameTotals

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total', SUM(Amount1 + Amount2), NULL
FROM nameTotals
WHERE rowNum=1;
```

Comment: Hello Mike and thanks for the response. I have been doing some tweaking and one partner of mine did find a good solution, let's check it out together:

In code you put:

`Dim Group as String = "0"

Function TotalPDV(ByVal ThisGroup as String, ByVal value as Integer) As Integer

   If Group = ThisGroup
   Return 0
 End If

 Group = ThisGroup
  
  Return value

End Function`

Then we make a calculated field in the DataSet like this:
`=Code.TotalPDV(Fields!<MyGroup>.Value, Fields!Amount1.Value + Fields!Amount2.Value)`

And it works.